# RobotFramework: how to write to log and override default color in case of keyword fail

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using `Robot Framework` and in case test failed the relevant `keyword` mark in red with FAIL `string`:

[image]

And in this case I want the log message (in the example screenshot: FALSE should be true) will mark in red color.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the test output into HTML using *HTML* marker. If you want to change color based on the test status, try calling following from your Test Teardown

```
*** Keywords ***
Enhance Test Status Display
    ${Color}= | Run Keyword If | ${TEST STATUS} == "FAIL" | Set variable | red
    ... | ELSE | Set variable | green

    ${TEST MESSAGE} = | Set Variable | *HTML*<p style="color:${Color}">${TEST MESSAGE}<p>

*** Test Cases ***
Image Comparison NOk
    [Test Teardown] | Enhance Test Status Display
    
    # Test case
```